# Changing the spatial resolution - stacked raster in R

Tags: r, resolution, resampling, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Want to change higher spatial resolution UAV dataset stacked in R. Used raster package to stack the individual band. Want to change the spatial resolution to 1 m.

```
stacked_UAV  <- stack(stack_list)
### Check the original resolution 
res(stacked_UAV)
0.0289 0.0289
## Number of rows original stacked image 
ncol(rast) <- stacked_UAV@ncols 
ncol(rast)
5193
## Number of rows original stacked image 
nrow(rast) <- stacked_UAV@nrows
nrow(rast)
13680
```

Tried following options using "raster package' but failed to get the target 1 m spatial resolution.

```
test_with_aggregate <- aggregate(stacked_UAV, fact=4)
res(test_with_aggregate)
0.1156 0.1156
```

Then tried to use the 'resample' function in the raster package but could not get the target spatial resolution due an error in setting spatial resolution to 1 m, this option is also not working.

```
### Empty stack
rast <- stack()
### Same spatial extend as the original stack 
extent(rast) <- stack(stacked_UAV) 
## Set resolution 
res(rast) <- 1
Error in x@layers[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
stacked_UAV_1 <- raster::resample(stacked_UAV, rast, method='bilinear')
```

Comment: `aggregate` with `fact=4` on a raster with resolution 0.0289 will produce a raster of resolution 0.0289 *4 = 0.1156. If you use `fact=35` you should get a raster with resolution 0.0289*35 = 1.0115. Is that close enough to a metre for your purposes?

Comment: Issue with I have time series of UAV data-sets. I want to have a consistent spatial resolution of 1 m across all the images.